# Angular End to end component test on form failing

Tags: angular, jasmine, angular-forms

I have a simple Angular form and want to test it with an end-to-end test. I.e. I want to drive the test from the UI. The test I have written does not work as I would expect.

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-foo',
    template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
    <input id="foo" type="text" formControlName="foo">
    <button id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>`
})
export class FooComponent implements OnInit {

    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            foo: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]+')]]
        });
    }
}
```

The test:

```
import { FooComponent } from './foo.component';
import { TestBed, ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule } from "@angular/forms";
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';

fdescribe('Foo component', () => {

    let component: FooComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<FooComponent>;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ReactiveFormsModule, FormsModule],
            declarations: [FooComponent]
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FooComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        component.ngOnInit();
    });

    it('should have a valid foo when input is valid', () => {
        let foo = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("#foo"));
        foo.nativeElement.value = "12345";
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component.form.controls.foo.valid).toBeTruthy();
    });

});
```

The test fails: `Expected false to be truthy.`. The `12345` value does not show up as the value for `component.form.controls.foo.value` when I debug into this piece although I do the `fixture.detectChanges()` beforehand.

What am I doing wrong?

[Here's a plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/R0BtQtLDIgOO2cnSF37Y?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seams like you need also to dispatch 'input' event like this:

```
input.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
```

Here is the full test fixed in [forked Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/e0mWnB6pBtHiVasQyms4?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! Do you know if this is documented anywhere in the Angular docs or it's more like a workaround?